# When I apply margin to an html element moves the whole page downwards

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I used margin on other elements successfully, yet when I try to do this with #searchbarcontainer it moves the entire page down. I'm trying to center it slightly below the middle of the page, but I can't work my way around this problem. I am trying to make somewhat of a Google clone and I'm new to HTML and CSS. Here is my code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-top: -40px;
  margin-right: -5px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.child {
  padding: 15px;
}

.link {
  color: rgb(95, 91, 91);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.link:hover {
  color: black;
}

#logo {
  margin-top: 110px;
  text-align: center;
}

#searchbarcontainer {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="form">
  <form action="https://google.com/search">
    <div id="searchbarcontainer">
      <input id="searchbar" type="text" name="q">
    </div>
    <div id="submitcontainer">
      <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Google Search">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<div id="nav">
  <div class="child">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light"><a class="link" href="images.html">Image Search</a></button>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light"><a class="link" href="advanced.html">Advanced Search</a></button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="logo">
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
</div>
```

Comment: `margin: 0 auto; position: relative; top: 10px;` can be applied to `searchbarcontainer` for a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

Your layout doesnt allow for the search bar container to be moved without affecting the entire page. You say that you want it to be lower, but as you can see in the picture, it has no where to go except to move everything down.

If you wanted to move it down you have to change it so that the search input and the "google search" button will be in the same container and center it that way
[image]

Comment: thank you very much man. I love this community

Answer (score 0):

when writing html, you have to write what you want to see in vertical order in your website
you've written from bottom to top instead

you've also made a lot of unnecessary elements

here's a somewhat streamlined version

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "sans-serif";
}

input {
  outline: 0;
  border: 0.3vh solid #bbb;
  font-size: 1.6vh;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 6.7vh;
  border-bottom: 0.2vh solid #bbb;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 0 3vh;
}

nav>div {
  height: 6.7vh;
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

nav>div>a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.6vh;
  background: yellow;
}

nav>div>a:first-child {
  margin-right: 1vh;
}

section {
  height: 93.3vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

section>img {
  width: 45vw;
  height: 15vh;
  object-fit: contain;
}

section>form {
  width: 45vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 3vh;
}

section>form>input[type="text"] {
  padding: 1vh;
  border-radius: 1vh;
  width: 65%;
}

section>form>input[type="submit"] {
  width: 25%;
  border-radius: 1vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Search</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <nav>
      <div><a href="images.html">Image Search</a><a href="advaced.html">Advanced Search</a></div>
    </nav>
    <section>
      <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
      <form action="https://google.com/search">
        <input id="searchbar" type="text" name="q" />
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Search" />
      </form>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Post an explanation for your code dump please

Comment: @j08691 hope that's better